# argumentless function, classes and templates

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am trying to do a numerical integration using the Romberg method implemented by numerical recipes in C++.

My problem is that I do not know how to handle constant variables in a 1D integral of a multi variable function, i.e. the integral of `f(x)dx` works, but I do not know the syntax for computing the integral of `f(x,y=2,z=5,...)dx`.

I believe that it has something to do with classes and templates, which I am not familiar with at all and me playing around with pointers, extra functions etc yielded no success.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <NR/nr3.h>
#include <NR/interp_1d.h>
#include <NR/quadrature.h>
#include <NR/romberg.h>

double fone (double x)          { return 2*x*x*x;   }
double ftwo (double x, double y){ return 2*x*x*x*y; }

int main()
{
    double Ione = qromb(fone, 1, 3);
    std::cout << Ione << std::endl;

    //double Itwo = qromb(ftwo(x, 2.0), 1, 3);
    //std::cout << Itwo << std::endl;
}
```

Here I am integrating `fone(x)` from `x=1` to 3. This code works, but if I uncomment the 3 lines above, i.e. trying to integrate `ftwo(x, 2)` from `x=1` to 3, I get

```
 invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘double&’ from an rvalue 
 of type ‘double’|
```

It seems like I am lacking the understanding of some basic concept in C++, but I do not know which one, which makes it hard to google the problem. This is also the first time I encountered that I could pass a function without an argument, i.e. `romberg(fone,..)` instead of `romberg(fone(x),..)` and I do not know how this is called.

If anyone could point me out the direction of what I need to study, I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: In the first case you pass a function pointer `fone` to the function `qromb`. In the second case you pass a double value `ftwo(x, 2.0)` to the function `qromb`. That is a big difference. You can use a wrapper function like a lambda.

Comment: If the non-written arguments always the same, then default argument is the way to go (e.g. `y=2` always unless explicitly stated otherwise).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use lambda to bind argument:

```
auto f2 = [](double x) { return ftwo(x, 2.0);};
Itwo = qromb(f2, 1, 3);
```

Comment: The question mentions NR in C++.

Comment: @PaulFloyd what do you mean?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am afraid it does not work. I still get an error ('invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘main()::<lambda(double)>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘main()::<lambda(double)>'). Do I have to add something to make it work in C++?

Comment: @Nicouh: As qromb expects (non-const) reference, you have to declare the lambda outside.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://github.com/leonid-pishchulin/humanshape/blob/master/shapemodel/lib/nr/romberg.h, the `qromb` function is defined as:

```
template <class T>
Doub qromb(T &func, Doub a, Doub b, const Doub eps=1.0e-10) { /* ... */ }
```

When you invoke

```
double Itwo = qromb(ftwo(x, 2.0), 1, 3);
```

you are passing an rvalue object of type `double` as the first argument (result of the `ftwo` function call). Therefore, the template parameter `T` is deduced to be `double` and the `func` parameter is an non-const lvalue reference to `double`. Which cannot be bound to rvalue argument (this is what the error message says.)

You likely want to make a unary function from `ftwo`, which you can do by using `std::bind` or lambda funciton as suggested by @Jarod42.